# Reformat text in in a file linux via a bash script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xml-parsing

I have a bunch of text files with XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<cdr core-uuid="dba286e1-8eb4-4792-9f3b-ff358c06bcad">\n  <channel_data>\n    <state>CS_REPORTING</state>\n    <direction>inbound</direction>\n    <state_number>11</state_number>\n
```

It is all on one line and I want to format each \n (newline char) into an actual line break and save the file.  How do I do this?

Comment: figured it out:  cat file | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'

Comment: Wasn't able to achieve it using `tr` yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command can do exactly this:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' input_file > output_file
```

This uses sed's substitution operator to replace all occurrences of "\n" with a newline character.  The substitution command follows the syntax

```
s/search_regex/replacement_text/operands
```

In this case, the search regex is '\n', which searches for a literal backslash followed by 'n', and it is replaced by the newline character '\n'.  The operand 'g' causes this to run over the whole file, not just the first occurrence.  Note also that the entire replacement string is quoted, so that bash doesn't do a level of escaping before passing to sed.

Try `man sed` or look here for more information:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sed -i.save -e 's/\\n/\n/g' <file>
```

It will edit the file in place, and save the original file with extension ".save".

Answer (score 1):

There is the quick and dirty regex method:

```
perl -pe 's!\n!<br/>!sg'
```

Not sure if it is sufficient for your needs though.

Comment: I have have misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
while read -r line ; do
  echo -e "$line"
done < "$infile" > "$outfile"
```

The quotes in the echo statement preserve all whitespaces.